# Asana task creation missing fields error

Tags: python, python-requests, asana

I am trying to create Asana task using oAuth, so far it was working fine, but suddenly its not working anymore.

It is throwing back the following response:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"missing both `parent` and `workspace` fields; at least one required"}]}
```

Here is what I am doing

```
import requests
import json

data = {
    'workspace':'<my workspace id>',
    'assignee':'me',
    'name':'My awesome task',
    'notes':'My task notes'
}
headers ={'Authorization':'Bearer <my token>','Content-Type':'application/json'}
response = requests.post('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks',
                         headers=headers,
                         data=json.dumps(data))
print response.text
```

Comment: @VincentBeltman Except the token and workspace id everything is same

Comment: You could try sending the data as headers. The Asana API accepts bouth. http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks

Comment: @VincentBeltman You mean curl?

Comment: No sending the parameters as headers instead of data

Comment: Its not in the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a `data` parameter in the payload. It's a common gotcha, but when you post JSON data to the API you need to send something that looks like this:

`{
  "data": {
    "name": "This is my task",
    "workspace": 1234,
    ...
  }
}`

In this case, you should be able to fix it by simply changing the last parameter to `data=json.dumps({ 'data': data })`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks But i just removed Content-Type header and sending raw dict to requests.post() and it worked!